# Jquery-UI Thickbox not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a query on the behaviour of the jquery-ui component **ThickBox**. The issue is,

Im using the thickbox in my master page. The login page of my website contains few asp controls where 'causesvalidation' property of the asp controls are set to 'true'. When the link associated with the thickbox class is clicked, the pages where validations are not set will show the hidden div . Why the same not working with the other pages where the validations are set to true? Is there any way to skip the validation when an anchor tag is used?

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the anchor a server control and set the CausesValidation property of the anchor in to false.  Also, ASP.NET has ValidationGroups, which might help you out as well.